# Finding suitable tests for changeset

Tags: integration-testing, code-coverage, changeset, automated-tests

We are using [cobertura](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/) as code coverage tool. The tests are done using RFT-Rational Functional Tester (500 odd tests). Running RFT takes quite long time. To encourage developers to run the RFT tests, we are thinking of tool that is capable of listing the tests that cover the 'change set'.

Approach is roughly:

1. On integration server run each rft test, create database for coverage data (.ser files for cobertura) against individual tests
2. for each change set, find the tests by going through the .ser files
3. Update the database when tests are run again.  Essentially the database from past runs are used to 'guess' a minimal test for the current change set.

To start with we may consider the change set as just list of files. It could, however, be line of code change.

Any comments? Any existing tools with this capability? Just came to know that IntelliJ 8 has this feature, for tests run within in. (Probably for unit tests)

Answer (score 0):

Current solution implemented is roughly (same as in the question )

1. Collect ser file per test basis
2. Create an database of affected classes    and methods

For a given change set generate list of methods and classes. Then check this against coverage database.  This gives an approximate solution.

Works reasonable, not 100%. So the filtering is only applied to small team specific changes.   Full test suite is run on main branch on a weekly basis